# How to avoid paste HTML contents for contenteditable="true" using ng-paste event

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

We are  using contenteditable attribute for inline edit purpose.

In inline edit we try to copy & paste any content the content will be pasted in “HTML and CSS “ itself.

Ex:

In list item we are try to copy & paste own list items it copied HTMl & CSS content itself.

```
<a contenteditable="true" ng-model="content" ng-paste="handlePaste($event.clipboardData.getData('text/plain'))" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched">one 1

<a ng-model="content" ng-paste="handlePaste($event.clipboardData.getData('text/plain'))" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" style="color: rgb(42, 100, 150); outline: -webkit-focus-ring-color auto 5px; outline-offset: -2px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">one 1</a>


</a>
```

We try to using  ng-paste="handlePaste($event.clipboardData.getData('text/plain'))" method for avoiding html content for avoiding HTML and CSS content  but did not working as expected.

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/4gCXHGO1wFuXF37uWIK2?p=preview)

Can any one please guide me